# How to run JMeter test from Jenkins

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

How to run jmeter test from Jenkins, here i want to run my  jmeter test with jenkins and tried to configure the Jenkins with Performance plugin based on the information got after googling.

In Google the solution is provided where jenkins is hosted locally and in Build we configure command line execution by providing jmx file path and so on...
the problem comes when my jenkins is in other server like http://172.27.80.57:8080/... here if i give Command line execution by providing jmx file path my build will fail..because my path is in different location..

So How to over come this as i am new to Jmeter and my boss want this result to be shown in jenkins ....and if there is any plugins which i need to install or is there any place where i am missing, please let me know ....this is very important for me....

OR is there any possibility that where we can push our changes to Git lab using CI tools such as Sourcetree...etc and then run those in Jenkins.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install Jenkins build agent to the machine which you plan to use as JMeter load generator, check out [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) Jenkins Wiki page.

Also JMeter test is possible using [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) feature. For more information check [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial/)

Hope this helps.